# how to add methods and a v-model to a <slot></slot>?

Tags: vue.js

basically I have a component called `"AddingMethodComponent"` that expects to be passed an HTML element and to this element I want to add the `@focus` event and the `v-model` that I have created inside `"AddingMethodComponent"`.

how can I do it?

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-8syygw?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2FAddingMethodComponent.vue

Main

```
<AddingMethodComponent>
  <input placeholder="write something.." />
</AddingMethodComponent>
```

AddingMethodComponent

```
<template>
  <div>Adding methods</div>
  <slot @focus="clicked" v-model="textModel"></slot>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AddingMethodComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      textModel: '',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.textModel = 'something';
    }, 2000);
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      console.log('click');
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by passing on the slot props to the input:

```html
<AddingMethodComponent v-slot="props">
  <input v-bind="props"/>
</AddingMethodComponent>
```

which is short for

```html
<AddingMethodComponent>
  <template v-slot:default="props">
    <input v-bind="props"/>
  </template>
</AddingMethodComponent>
```

However, using `v-model` on slots is dicey. It looks like it adds the `@update:modelValue` listener, but not the `:modelValue` prop. So it works half-way with Vue components. But it will not work with native inputs, where you would need `:value` and `@input`.

I think one way or another, you are better off by specifically setting prop and listener instead of the shorthand `v-model`, i.e. if you use native inputs:

```html
<slot
  :value="textModel"
  @input="event => textModel = event.target.value"
></slot>
```

And if you use Vue components:

```html
<slot
  :modelValue="textModel"
  @update:modelValue="value => textModel = value"
></slot>
```

Here it is in [the updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-iapxsm?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2FAddingMethodComponent.vue)

---

Update: Turns out you are using Vue 2, where events are not parts of attrs. So you have to provide props and listeners separately:

```html
<slot
  :props="{value: textValue}" 
  :on="{input: e => textValue = e}"
/>
```

and then also bind them separately with `v-bind` and `v-on`:

```html
<AddingMethodComponent v-slot="{props, on}">
  <mds-search-field v-bind="props" v-on="on"/>
</AddingMethodComponent>
```

```js
const SlotComponent = {
  template: `
    <div>
      Here is the slot:
      <slot
        :props="{value: textValue}" 
        :on="{input: e => textValue = e}"
      />
      Value in parent: <i>{{ textValue }}</i>
    </div>
  `,
  
  data(){
    return {
      textValue: 'initial parent value'
    }
  },
}

const InputComponent = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['value'],
  emit: ['input']
}


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    SlotComponent,
    InputComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      test: 'value'
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <slot-component v-slot="{props, on}">
    <input-component v-bind="props" v-on="on"/>
  </slot-component>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i really appreciate your help on this example works. i know what i am about to say is out of the scope of this question. in my actual code i have an input search field component that i import from an external library. and by doing what you did here, it never updates the v-model variable nor does the click events work for example... do you know why this could happen?

Comment: thank you genious!! this is the library https://designsystem.morningstar.com/components/search-field/?version=4.3.16&tab=variations

Comment: maybe @input event is not triggered, I thought that

Comment: @input not works.. but :value="textModel" input search show the current value of the "textModel"

Comment: yes! I use vue 2 sorry for not say that

Comment: you are the smartest person I've ever met in stack overflow!!

Comment: taking advantage of your infinite wisdom and kindness.... How can I get the value of the text field from the main? in this example I tried to get the value by adding :value="textModel". https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-j1xz7a?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2FAddingMethodComponent.vue

Comment: Here is how you would bind the values together in Vue 3: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-oj8d7m?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2FAddingMethodComponent.vue

Comment: Crack, I hope you are well, how can I set a `ref` in <slot> (using vue2)?

Comment: Hey, hope you are well too! Not sure what you mean though. Probably best to ask a new question